# Progressive Upload File in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, file-upload

in the [angular.io](https://angular.io/guide/http#listening-to-progress-events) site there is an uploader service uploading a file, but it's not complete class is there a rich class sample for uploading data with the best functionality and pattern contain progressive error Handling and set headers and etc ...?
The angular class suggested contains code below:

```
  private getEventMessage(event: HttpEvent<any>, file: File) {
    switch (event.type) {
      case HttpEventType.Sent:
        return `Uploading file "${file.name}" of size ${file.size}.`;

      case HttpEventType.UploadProgress:
        // Compute and show the % done:
        const percentDone = Math.round(100 * event.loaded / event.total);
        return `File "${file.name}" is ${percentDone}% uploaded.`;

      case HttpEventType.Response:
        return `File "${file.name}" was completely uploaded!`;

      default:
        return `File "${file.name}" surprising upload event: ${event.type}.`;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative could be using https://github.com/kzrfaisal/angular-file-uploader. 
You can find more details at https://github.com/kzrfaisal/angular-file-uploader